# apt-get command error loading shared libraries

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, raspbian, apt-get

I am trying to install PHP and a tutorial said to uninstall gnupg2, however, I now cannot run apt-get.
when I type apt-get it gives me the error:

> apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12:
>   cannot open 
>       shared object file: No such file or directory

How do I fix this?